# PHP post from two forms in different div containers (generated by ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two div containers which update two different forms through ajax. Is it possible to serialize the data from both forms with ajax? So that I could use the inputs from the two forms as POST in php.

If both forms were in the same div, I could do this, but in this case I can't, right?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'calculate.php', 
    data:$('#form1, #form2').serialize(), 
    success: function(response) {
        $('#results').html(response).slideDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'calculate.php', 
    data:$('#form1').serialize() + '&' +$('#form2').serialize(), 
    success: function(response) {
    $('#results').html(response).slideDown();
}
```